# Is "reality" a formal word?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, formality

I am wondering, can the word **reality** be used in a formal text?

For example can I say: "It has some application in reality". I mean "It has some application in real world problems".

By a formal text I mean a text that can be appeared in my thesis or paper.

I used that in my thesis and my professor said that it is not a formal word and I cannot use it in my thesis!

Comment: would you please tell us what your definition of *formal text* is?

Comment: @haha  I mean a text that can be appeared in my thesis or paper.

Comment: So, the next question would be what makes you think you can/cannot use it in your thesis.

Comment: By the way, there is a difference between *"reality is a formal word"* and *"in reality is a formal word"*. So, I suggest that you should edit your title question and please do add some more information.

Comment: @haha I used that in my thesis and my professor said that it is not a formal word and I cannot use it in my thesis!

Comment: Well, that's better. For some unknown reason (at least for me) I cannot edit you question, but as i said it's best for you to add these information you just said in comments into your question, and i'm sure someone more knowledgeable than me weighs in.

Comment: The question about formality is not the actual issue here, and use of the word 'formal' is misleading. The real problem is that 'In reality' defaults to the pragmatic usage 'Actually, ...', no matter how formal the register.   "It has some application in real world problems" is far preferable to "It has some application in reality".

Comment: Or something with "practice". E.G. "It has some application in practice" or "some practical application", without "reality".